# Persisting data beyond the lifetime of a callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

Forgive me if this is a commonly asked question, I'm new to JavaScript.

I'm attempting to use the library "video-url-link" from [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-url-link/v/0.1.2).

The Readme provides the following example:

```
videoUrlLink.twitter.getInfo('https://twitter.com/{@}/status/{ID}', {}, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(info.full_text);
        console.log(info.variants);
    }
});
```

This works fine, but what are my options if I want the "info" object to persist outside of the scope of the callback?

I've tried declaring a variable outside the getInfo call, then setting it inside the callback, which I didn't expect to work - and it doesn't work(!)

What I have is:

```
const get_twitter_video_info = (video_url) => {

    var nfo = {};

    try
    {
        videoUrlLink.twitter.getInfo(
            video_url,
            {},
            (error, video_info) => {

                if (error !== undefined)
                    console.log(error);

                if (video_info !== undefined)
                {
                    nfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(video_info));
                }
            }
        );
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log (err);
        throw(err);
    }

    return nfo;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: you could move the `nfo` variable outside the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting return *nfo* before the callback is even called. In the code, *get_twitter_video_info* will return an empty object and then *getInfo* will return the response and the callback will be called (where you are using *nfo* and *video_info*). You can either utilise *nfo* in the callback itself and process further or you can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: I tried async / await, but kept getting the error callback being called.  I think I'll abandon this lib.  thanks anyways.